# Ruby how to modify parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

so i have this code that and my aim was to convert any empty string to null

```
def convert_empty_strings_to_null
  if request.patch? || request.post?
    convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec(request.params)
  end
end

def convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec(param)
  param = nil if param.empty? if param.is_a?(String)
  param.all?{|v| convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec v} if param.is_a?(Array)
  param.all?{|k,v| convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec v} if param.is_a?(Hash)
end
```

But i'm new to ruby on rails and i found it that it sends params by value and not by reference, so no change in params is made, how do i fix this ?

Comment: Note that `all?` does not replace anything. Use `map` instead. In case of the hash, use `param.map{ |k,v| [x,y] }.to_h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by "empty" you mean zero-with strings, meaning that strings consisting only of whitespace should be left intact. (Otherwise `blank?` and `strip` would be your friends.)

```
def convert_empty_strings_to_nil
  if request.patch? || request.post?
    request.params.each do |key, value| 
      request.params[key] = convert_empty_strings_to_nil_rec(value)
    end
  end
end

def convert_empty_strings_to_nil_rec(param)
  case param
  when String
    param.empty? ? nil : param
  when Array
    param.map{ |v| convert_empty_strings_to_nil_rec(v) }
  when Hash
    param.map{ |k,v| [k, convert_empty_strings_to_nil_rec(v)] }.to_h
  else
    param
  end
end
```

Comment: This would fix the problem but apparently the operator '=' isn't defined for params, is there a way to iterate over params and change the elements themselves without creating a new object?

Comment: There are two ways: (1) Store the returned modified params hash in a new instance variable and use these. (2) Yes, knowing that `request.params` is always a hash, we can modify its values in-place. Should I elaborate?

Comment: Thanks i solved it by calling the recursive call on the first level of request.params for each value

Comment: Cool! I updated the answer accordingly. Feel free to mark it as the accepted answer anytime :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this is how your `convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec` method should be, for keeping the changes persistent:

```
def convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec(param)
      if param == ""
        updated_param == nil
      elsif param.is_a?(Array)
        updated_param == param.map{|x| nil if x.empty? }        
      elsif param.is_a?(Hash)
        updated_param = {}
        param.each do |k, v| 
            if v.empty?  
                updated_param[k] = nil
            else
                updated_param[k] = v
            end
        end
      end
      return updated_param
end
```

Further, I am assuming from your question that `convert_empty_strings_to_null` is a action method. It should be updated to catch what `convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec` method is returning.

```
def convert_empty_strings_to_null
  if request.patch? || request.post?
    updated_params = convert_empty_strings_to_null_rec(request.params)
  end
  # you can use the updated_params here on in this action method
end
```

Hope it helps : )